# How can I create a dynamic domain class in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

How can I create a dynamic domain class in Grails.

Let's say I want to create a new domain class whose class name and properties is known in the run-time. How to create it and persist it in Grails?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 4):

There's a plugin for that: http://www.grails.org/plugin/dynamic-domain-class

Comment: *There's a plugin for that.* That sounds suspiciously Apple-like... :-)

Comment: Ironic given how much I dislike Apple.

Comment: Hi Burt, is it just me or this plugin "breaks" the auto reload of other controllers in Grails 1.7.2?

Answer (score 2):

the plugin seems to be abandoned, and in the google group of the project the deveoper say that there is some important issue and he said we can't using it in production, and there is no evolution since 2011, I hope that the founder of the idea Burt Beckwith can help us to continue this plugin, because it is really an interesting thing, there is too much possiblity behind the scene.

Comment: After I had success creating dynamic controllers at runtime (used in the http://grails.org/plugin/dynamic-controller and http://grails.org/plugin/app-info plugins) I tried to do the same for domain classes. I got it basically working, but because of how much work Hibernate does at startup I don't know how practical the whole approach is. I'm not sure how much work it would be to get things working in newer Grails versions. If someone could show some read-world uses for this feature I might try to find time to revisit it.

Comment: I think the biggest impediment is that in 2.0+ most of the methods and behavior added to the domain classes is at compile time using AST transforms, so you would ideally need to do this plugin's work before hose fire, and that is not at all easy to do

Comment: ooo the possibilities are huge, it is the same case as manipulating the metamodel of something there are always a powerfull functionnalities behind it, for exemple in java with the couple classloader and the introspection apis we can generate code an execute it on the fly, the application can change these properties, functionnalities, the application can change itself, adding new components, this is a huge addition==>

Comment: in the case of grails imagine that we can generate an entire web site dynamically or we can transform an ontology or folksonomy to a web site dynamically without coding, it will be amazing, ok it is not an easy task but it will be possible, image also that the user can change his web app on runtime, adding new fields and generating new forms, adding new domain and link it to the existing schema==>

Comment: we can even create an app for creating website graphically through some functionnality like, create domain, link to an other domain and generate interface to display it, I think all the creators of CMS or ERP will be very happy, for the ERP it can resolve the problem of the heterogenity between modules, because now we can modify the shema on the fly==>

Comment: using some technics in data mining we can change dynamically the new learned cancepts into domain the result will be the enrichment of knowledge base, without coding, without stoping the system, on the fly and automatic.

Comment: One use-case that I'm struggling is about a statistics system that need to create dynamic tables for new stats and couters in run-time. Actually having domain classes is not very required here, but it will be great having table creation be managed through Hibernate or GORM, as asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30192096/grails-how-create-table-in-run-time-using-dialect)

Answer (score -1):

I'm working to get this to work on grails 2.4.4, I'm very close at getting it to work, only need to make a new instance of sessionfactory to work :)

Comment: Please consider responding to the old questions only if you have specific solutions which might help others?