# Grails, How Create Table in Run-time Using Dialect

Tags: database, grails

Is it possible to create tables in run-time without being worry about create table proprietary syntax of different databases and other things that can be managed by GORM or Hibernate ?

I need to create and manage somes table dynamically in run-time and don't need to ORM for them.

Answer (score 1):

Hey it seems this question was asked in the question [how can i create a dynamic domain class in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447048/how-can-i-create-a-dynamic-domain-class-in-grails). Yet Burt's answer of the [dynamic domain class](http://grails.org/plugin/dynamic-domain-class) plugin seems to be abandoned.

I would recommend using raw SQL for now as described in the [SQL Groovy Docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html).
Here is a quick example (make sure your database id has proper permissions)

```
def sql = new Sql(dataSource)

sql.execute '''
    create table PROJECT (
        id integer not null,
        name varchar(50),
        url varchar(100),
    )
    ''' 
sql.close()
```

Comment: It is needed to not use the raw sql like it, to manage different databases syntax or features out of the application.

Comment: Ah yeah that is great about GROM.  Maybe take a look at the decrepit [grails-dynamic-domain-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/grails-dynamic-domain-class-plugin/) you might be able to gleam some information or even better get it working! Good luck I hope this helps!